# What is difference between callbacks in pending_queue and poll_queue of event loop in Node.js

Tags: node.js, event-loop, libuv

[image]

As we can see in above Libuv code for event loop, first callbacks in pending_queue runs. After that I/O Polling happens. So what is the difference between I/O callbacks in pending_queue and poll_queue?

Comment: Did you read the design overview? http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/design.html#the-i-o-loop

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Things are clear now. I have one question from this design review doc:
It is written "The loop blocks for I/O. At this point the loop will block for I/O for the duration calculated in the previous step."
If suppose the timeout for I/O blocking come as 0, and there are callbacks in poll_queue and check_queue. Will the I/O poll phase exit and directly go to check_queue without executing callbacks in poll_queue?

Comment: Nothing in the documentation suggests that callbacks in the poll queue will be skipped if the I/O timeout is 0.

Answer (score 0):

**poll callbacks** are those who have finished their execution and waiting for the event loop to pick them up and pass them to the event/message queue and then to the call stack on a FIFO basis.

They are the callbacks that are ready to be executed. >> THEY ARE Done/Ready/Finished/Processed >> they are waiting for the event loop to pick them up to pass them to the message queue and then to the call stack.

**pending callbacks** are those that are still waiting/pending/in-thread/processing callbacks and waiting for the appropriate tick to handle them when they are actually finished.

They are the callbacks that are deferred/postponed to the next loop iteration. >> they are still/waiting/processing/in-thread.